# div position argument breaks slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to integrate a simple slider within my website and found [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/AtFeF/79/) on jsfiddle

I do want to place the slider "relative" within my website, but if I change the css to 
`position: relative;`     the slider does not work properly anymore, as it now displays the fading images above one another [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/AtFeF/82/)

Why is this happening and how can I position the slider-div "relative" within my website?
I tried wrapping it with another div-layer but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a wrapper `div` as you say.

You should put your slider inside another `div` and then position this wrapper `div` relative.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">//<--Add here tha wrapper div
<div id="banner_area">
    <img class="active" src="http://viewallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Uluru-Australia.jpg" />
    <img src="http://www.wallpaperhi.com/thumbnails/detail/20130309/ocean%20beach%20rocks%20australia%201920x1200%20wallpaper_www.wallpaperhi.com_71.jpg" />
    <img src="http://www.star.com.au/star-event-centre/PublishingImages/about-sydney-800x500.jpg" />
    <img src="http://www.ytravelblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Whitsunday-Islands-Queensland-Australia-6.jpg" />
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrap{
    position:relative;
    top:100px;
    left:100px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AtFeF/83/)

**UPDATE**

To float within the website add a `height` to the `#wrap`

```
#wrap{
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    left:100px;
    height:250px;
}
```

[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/AtFeF/89/)

Comment: thanks for your reply!
But now the slider does not float within the website. For instance, I'd like it to be between asdf and jklo:
http://jsfiddle.net/AtFeF/87/

Comment: @user2926577 I updated the answer. Is this solution works for you?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a wrapper. You are setting `position: relative` on the wrong element. Set it on `#banner_area`, not `#banner_area img`. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AtFeF/84/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but now the slider does not float within the website. For instance, I'd like it to be between aaaa and bbbb:
http://jsfiddle.net/AtFeF/86/